# How to properly add changes to releted lists to the repository?

Tags: page-layout, cicd

I have a task to make changes to the display of fields in a standard related list. For this purpose, I create a scratch org and make changes. Then I use the commands:

> sfdx force:source:status

> sfdx force:source:pull

Then, from all the changes that have appeared on scratch org, I select my changes and commit them to the repository.
changed files:
[image]

example of changes:
[image]

Then CI/CD [Bitbucket pipelines] creates scratchorg and checks if my changes are ok by deploying (check only) to the standard sandbox and pushing the new code to the newly created scratchorg. Deploy to sandbox is ok, and on scratchorg these errors appear:

```
  TYPE   PROJECT PATH                                                                                    PROBLEM
─────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Error  force-app/main/default/objects/ProfileSkill/ProfileSkill.object-meta.xml                        Invalid fullName, must end in a custom suffix ( for ex. __c )
Error  force-app/main/default/objects/ProfileSkillEndorsement/ProfileSkillEndorsement.object-meta.xml  Invalid fullName, must end in a custom suffix ( for ex. __c )
Error  force-app/main/default/objects/ProfileSkillUser/ProfileSkillUser.object-meta.xml                Invalid fullName, must end in a custom suffix ( for ex. __c )
Error  force-app/main/default/layouts/ProfileSkill-Skill Layout.layout-meta.xml                        Parent entity failed to deploy
Error  force-app/main/default/layouts/UserAlt-User Profile Layout.layout-meta.xml                      Invalid field:ProfileSkill in related list:ProfileSkillUserByUserRelatedList
Error  force-app/main/default/layouts/ProfileSkillUser-Skill User Layout.layout-meta.xml               Parent entity failed to deploy
Error  force-app/main/default/layouts/ProfileSkillEndorsement-Endorsement Layout.layout-meta.xml       Parent entity failed to deploy
Error  force-app/main/default/profiles/Admin.profile-meta.xml                                          In field: layout - no Layout named ProfileSkill-Skill Layout found (4988:24)
Error  force-app/main/default/profiles/XXXX Standard User.profile-meta.xml                             In field: layout - no Layout named ProfileSkill-Skill Layout found (4978:24)
Error  force-app/main/default/sharingRules/ProfileSkill.sharingRules-meta.xml                          Required field is missing: sharingCriteriaRules
ERROR running force:source:push:  Push failed. 
Try this: 
Check the order of your dependencies and ensure all metadata is included.
```

def.json:

```
{
  "orgName": "Scratchorg",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi","PersonAccounts", "Communities","DebugApex", "API","RecordTypes","SocialCustomerService","B2BCommerce","DefaultWorkflowUser"],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "quoteSettings": {
      "enableQuote": true
    },
    "communitiesSettings": {
      "enableNetworksEnabled": true,
      "enableEnablePRM": true
    },
    "sharingSettings": {
      "enableExternalSharingModel": true
    },
    "ideasSettings": {
      "enableIdeas": true
    },
    "accountSettings": {
      "enableRelateContactToMultipleAccounts": true
    },
    "enhancedNotesSettings": {
      "enableEnhancedNotes": true
    },
    "experienceBundleSettings": {
      "enableExperienceBundleMetadata": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    },
    "apexSettings": {
        "enableApexApprovalLockUnlock": true
    }
  }
}
```

Questions:

1. how should changes of this type be pushed?
2. why do these errors occur?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error isn't really stemming from your changes per se. Rather, what's happening is that somewhere along the line, whether from this change or another, your Page Layouts and Profiles have picked up references to features that are present in some org shapes but not in others. This is a common issue with Profiles and Page Layouts. Additionally, it looks like your source tree may have picked up some extra metadata for the ProfileSkill object. You'll want to review your retrieve and commit carefully to ensure that only changes you intended to make are included.

While it may be necessary in fixing this to remove the problematic references identified by the error messages, you may also want to review to ensure that you are using the same scratch org shape (configuration) in your local development and in your CI system. This helps to avoid such feature mismatches. The fact that your sandbox deployment works suggests that your local scratch org shape is compatible with your sandbox and production org.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the problem disappeared on the 3rd pipeline rerun without making any changes.